Filtering records by month and year - RazorPage/C#
I am trying to filter my records by month and year. The filtering for the month works fine, but the filter for the year doesn't.
For some reason if I try to change the year it always sets the value for my SelectedYear-Property to "01/01/0001", or if I set a default value for my SelectedYear-Property (e.g. DateTime.Today) and if I try to change it it always hops back to the default value.
Maybe you can help me I can't figure out where the problem is.
Probably has something to do with wrong ModelBinding?
Here is my code:
Index.cshtml.cs
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly CMSContext _context;
    private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;

    public IndexModel(CMSContext context, ILogger<IndexModel> logger) 
    {
        _context = context;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public IList<TimeManagementModel> TimeManagementModel { get; set; }

    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public DateTime SelectedMonth { get; set; } = DateTime.Today;

    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public DateTime SelectedYear { get; set; } = DateTime.Today;

    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("SelectedYear value: {SelectedYear}", SelectedYear);

        TimeManagementModel = await _context.TimeManagerModel
        .Where(x => x.Date.Month == SelectedMonth.Month && x.Date.Year == SelectedYear.Year)
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)
        .ToListAsync();


        CalculateDailyWorkedHours();
        CalculateOvertime(7.7);
    }
}

Index.cshtml
@page
@model TestRazor.Pages.TimeManager.IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "TimeManager";
}

<h1>Time Manager</h1>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/TimeManager.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <a asp-page="Create" class="btn btn-success">Create New</a>
    </p>

    <form method="get">
        <div style="display: flex">
            <div style="margin-right: 10px;">
                <label for="selectedMonth">Select Month:</label>
                <select name="SelectedMonth" id="selectedMonth" class="form-control" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                    @{
                        var today = DateTime.Today;
                        var selectedMonthValue = Model.SelectedMonth.ToString("yyyy-MM");
                        var months = Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(i => new DateTime(today.Year, i, 1));

                        foreach (var month in months)
                        {
                            <option value="@month.ToString("yyyy-MM")" selected="@(selectedMonthValue == month.ToString("yyyy-MM"))">
                                @month.ToString("MMMM")
                            </option>
                        }
                    }
                </select>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="selectedYear">Select Year:</label>
                <select name="SelectedYear" id="selectedYear" class="form-control" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                    @{
                        var currentYear = DateTime.Today.Year;

                        for (var year = currentYear - 5; year <= currentYear + 5; year++)
                        {
                            <option value="@year" selected="@(Model.SelectedYear.Year == year)">@year</option>
                        }
                    }
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

</body>


It looks like you need a local year variable in your for loop.  Search on here for Blazor For loop to find out why.

Your SelectedYear in backend is type of Datetime, but your frontend year value is an int/string type which cannot be converted to Datetime by default.
One way is to change your backend type to int/string.
[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
public int SelectedYear { get; set; }

                    

And
<option value="@year" selected="@(Model.SelectedYear == year)">@year</option>

Another way is to set the value with Datetime in frontend:
<option value="@(new DateTime(year,1,1).ToString("yyyy-MM"))" selected="@(Model.SelectedYear.Year == year)">@year</option>

